# Filter and absolute sorting on pandas dataframe throws an index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter my dataframe and then sort it on one column using absolute value.

If i try to sort without using filter, its working but with filter it gives me error. Below is the code i am using:

```
df[(df['Core']=='Europe')].iloc[df['Value1'].abs().argsort()].reset_index(drop=True) # Does not work
df.iloc[df['Value1'].abs().argsort()].reset_index(drop=True) # Works properly
```

Error reported is as follows:

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you really need `.iloc`, maybe `.loc` is the function for you?

Comment: You are filtering your dataframe then sorting and indexing your dataframe using the unfilter dataframe.  Hence you are picking up some indexes that don't exists in your filtered dataframe.

Comment: As @ScottBoston said.  To be more detailed: `df[(df['Core']=='Europe')]` is going to filter the dataframe so that not all of the `df['Value1']`s will be available. Then you try to select all of them with the `iloc[df['Value1'].abs().argsort()]` call.  But they are not all there.

Comment: ok, now i understand. What should be the syntax for that if i want to use the filtered dataframe? Should i use two rows of syntax?

Comment: Using the newest version of pandas 1.1 `sort_values` has a new parameter `key`.   So, a syntax that woudl work for you using the latest version of pandas would be something like this: `df[df['Core'] == "Europe"].sort_values('Value1', key=lambda x: x.abs())`